# Is it possible, I would find the Facebook group by name via Facebook Graph API to list out more than 1000 groups?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I try use Facebook Graph API to find it. It works well But the list of groups that I find it displayed less than 150 groups.

An example URL that I tested.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/searchaccess_token=mytoken&q=keyword&type=group&limit=1000
```

Is there a way to make it show what more than 150 groups?

I developed using PHP

Comment: I try use pagination. But not working.

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: I use the pagination, but it did not work as I want. I have tried all of the count when press Next. I counted no more than 150 groups.