# Search facebook group using the name as a search term on Facebook FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I've tried using the Facebook Graph API. But the results came out, it did not show up to 150 groups. I'm not sure that it is a limitation of Facebook or not.

**An example URL that I tested.**

Now, I would like to test the FQL Query. But did not succeed. I have the following error

> (#604) Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql

This is a SQL statement

```
SELECT gid, name, privacy FROM group WHERE strpos(name, "programming") >= 0
```

Comment: did you create a new account for the same question? > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36630777/is-it-possible-i-would-find-the-facebook-group-by-name-via-facebook-graph-api-t - btw, FQL is deprecated since a very long time.

Comment: It has no other way to make the results show more than this?

Comment: no, you have to use paging. if it only returns 150, then that´s most likely a limit. in reality, you should not need that many anyway.